# Please help with this beta code, How can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, dry, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't this code produce the desired result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674145/why-doesnt-this-code-produce-the-desired-result)

I have the code:

```
def check_beta_code
    beta_code_array = ['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE']
    beta_code_array.each do |code|
        if :beta_code != code
            errors.add(:beta_code, "Invalid Beta Code")
        end
    end 
end
```

The problem with this code is that even if someone inputs a correct password, 4 errors are still generated because the other 4 aren't correct.

Comment: Presumably you want to return without an error if a code matches. If so then you should be returning if there is a match and failing if you get below the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this code is in a model somewhere. You can try creating a model that holds the beta codes and store some values in the DB. Then it's just a matter of querying the db for the code and seeing if there's a match:

```
# model
class BetaCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assumes a field named 'code'
end

# add some codes (via migration, console, manually, etc)
['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE'].each do |code|
  BetaCode.create(:code => code )
end

# and check for a match when user submits code (controller)
@code = BetaCode.find_by_code(user_code)

if @code.present?
  # user is approved
else
  # sorry, no luck
end
```

If you want to use your snippet, you can always use the `member?` method for an array.

Comment: Thanks, i used this but inside found `includes?`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to see if the array contains a specific code, so you should use the `find_index` method. It returns the index of the element you're looking for, or `nil` when the element can't be found (this is the case that interests us).

```
def check_beta_code(code)
    beta_code_array = ['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE']
    return beta_code_array.find_index(code) != nil
end

check_beta_code 'foobar' # false
check_beta_code 'AAAAAAAAAA' # true
```

Comment: ` def check_beta_code
   errors.add(:beta_code, "Invalid Beta Code") if !(corect_code?(:beta_code))
 end
 
 def correct_code?(code)
  beta_code_array = ['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE']
  return beta_code_array.find_index(code)
 end
end` Would this work?

Comment: @Planetpluto, I suppose it would. You should check yourself though.