# Why doesn't this code produce the desired result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def check_beta_code
    beta_code_array = ['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE']

    if false == beta_code_array.include?(:beta_code)
        errors.add(:beta_code, "Invalid Beta Code")
    end
end
```

I created a user, `user = User.new{:beta_code=>'AAAAAAAAAA'}` and then `user.save #=> false` and then i do `user.errors #=>{:beta_code=>["Invalid Beta Code"]}`

Why is it giving the error even though :beta_code is equal to one of the values?
Help!

Comment: Why do you need the "if false ==" part of that statement? A simpler way to write that line would be "unless beta_code_array.include?(beta_code)".

Comment: +1 Preacher, I'll change this in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at your conditional:

```
beta_code_array.include?(:beta_code)
```

You're checking if `beta_code_array` includes a symbol `:beta_code`. I assume you meant to pass on a string parameter? I'm not too familiar with Rails — please correct me if this isn't the right form for the User model.

```
def check_beta_code beta_code
    beta_code_array = ['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDDDDDD', 'EEEEEEEEEE']

    unless beta_code_array.include?(beta_code)
        errors.add(:beta_code, "Invalid Beta Code")
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm pretty new to rails and coding in general